# Can I detect client operating system to be specifically Mac snow leopard in jquery?

Tags: jquery, operating-system, osx-snow-leopard

I am creating a download page , I want only, user who are using MAC Snow Leopard Operating System to be redirected to this page. Can I detect specifically snow leopard OS users through jquery?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can get an (unreliable) glimpse at what OS version is running by analyzing the User-Agent string.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

The core of this script is the following code:

```
this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent)
        || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion)
        || "an unknown version";
```

Note you need to consider both the "userAgent" and the "appVersion", depending on the exact browser.

Different browsers often report the OS in slightly different ways. Take a look at these lists to see how the big three Mac browsers do it -- Snow Leopard browsers often contain the string "10_6_" or "10.6" somewhere to indicate it's Mac OS 10.6.n:

http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Safari/

http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/

http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Firefox/

All together, you can try something like this, which is absolutely not rigorously tested by me:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent ||navigator.appVersion;
if (ua.match(/10[_.]6/)) { // null if not matched
    alert('Snow Leopard');
} else {
    alert('not Snow Leopard');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8BxUC/2/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get that information out of `navigator.appVersion` or `navigator.userAgent`

Answer (score 0):

All you can go by is the user agent:

```
$('#UserAgent').val(navigator.userAgent);
```

It will look something like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/534.53.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.3 Safari/534.53.10
```

Answer (score 0):

Using navigator.userAgent to determine the platform, it is vulnerable to spoofing by the user or misrepresentation by the browser itself. It is always best to avoid browser-specific code entirely where possible.